# In a loop, do not display content that does not have a thumbnail

Tags: multisite, post-thumbnails, loop

In a multisite installation, I have a loop set up on my main blog that displays all posts from sub blogs, along with a thumbnail image.  The image is important and without one will break the grid.

Is there a way to reject posts that do not have a featured image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) function. 
From the codex:

```
<?php 
//This must be in one loop

if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution: using a default image if one isn't supplied by the user.  Would it be terrible difficult to set up some conditional statements to use a different image based on post format?

Comment: No, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats, you may do a switch / if block using has_post_format('your_format_of_choiche'). Note that you need Wordpress > 3.1 to do that!